# What do these Big-O notations mean in context of comparison

Tags: big-o-notation

What do the following mean, in the context of `greater than`, or `smaller than`?

$$
O(n \log ⁡n) > O(n)
$$

$$
O(nlogn) < O(n^2)
$$

Comment: Where you find such inequalities?

Comment: @zkutch, what do you mean by "inequalities" ?

Comment: I want to understand what: `>` or `<` between two Big-O notations for time complexity implies or means? Does it mean that the one that is greater is better, or the one that is less then is greater?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, this comparison means the `subset of`. Hence, $O(n\log n) > O(n)$ means All members of $O(n)$ exist in $O(n \log n)$ as well or $O(n) \subset O(n \log n)$. For example, $f(n) = \sqrt{n} \in O(n)$ and $f(n) \in  O(n\log n) $ and $g(n) = n \log n \not \in O(n)$ and $g(n) \ \in O(n \log n)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I've seen this before, but, wasn't so sure. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSmith Please see the new included example.

Comment: So, if, **Algorithm1** is $$O(n)$$, and we modify it so, that it includes $$O(NlogN)$$, then we can exclude $$O(n)$$, and then the new algorithm is more dominant thus: $$O(n \log ⁡n) > O(n)$$

Comment: So, what does this statement mean: $$O(nlogn) < O(n^2)$$ ??

Comment: @JohnSmith You can interpret $O(n\log n) < O(n^2)$ such as the other case. For example, $n \sqrt{n} \in O(n^2)$, but it is not in $O(n\log n)$.